# Passing multiple variables in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have been trying to follow an example online where I am passing variables using AJAX to PHP

It worked but I managed to only pass 1 variable through using AJAX, but I need to pass multiple variables, I tried to add it on but it didn't work any help would be appreciated

I tried to add it on like this `var url = 'ajax.php?js_var=' + js_var + gender;` but it just printed it out on the same line.

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Pass variable from PHP to JavaScript - Cyberster's Blog'</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <a href="#" id="link">Click me!</a>
    <div id="update"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var js_var = "M";    
        var gender = "hey";
        document.getElementById("link").onclick = function () {        
            // ajax start
            var xhr;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // all browsers
            else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  // for IE

            var url = 'ajax.php?js_var=' + js_var + gender;
            xhr.open('GET', url, false);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState===4 && xhr.status===200) {
                    var div = document.getElementById('update');
                    div.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
            // ajax stop
            return false;
        }
    </script>
  </body>
  <?php
    if (isset($_GET['js_var'])) $php_var = $_GET['js_var']  ;
    else $php_var = "<br />js_var is not set!";

     if (isset($_GET['gender'])) $php_var1 = $_GET['gender'] ;
    else $php_var1 = "<br />js_var is not set!";

echo $php_var;
echo $php_var1;

?>
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery at ?

Comment: You are trying to access a GET parameter named `gender`, but you have not put a parameter by that name into your URL’s query string. Please go look up the basics of GET parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer...

```
var url = 'ajax.php?js_var=' + js_var + '&gender=' + gender;
```

Better answer

```
var params = {
    "js_var": js_var,
    "gender": gender
};

var queryParams = Object.keys(params).map(function(k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k]);
}).join('&');

var url = 'ajax.php?' + queryParams;
```

If you need to support IE versions < 9, see the following shims for [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map#Compatibility) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Compatibility).